# what Windows api would I need to build remote desktop tool like TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, winapi, remote-desktop

judging by low bandwidth footprint I am guessing that TeamViewer doesn't just transmit the screen pixel by pixel. So what api would such a tool use to obtain graphics features for efficient transmission? Are there open source apps like "poor man's TeamViewer" demonstrating this in code?

ETA: I am not asking for "specific api" for "complex task". My question boils down to "how does TeamViewer work, in terms of obtaining graphics info from Windows?"

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC). But asking for a specific API to do a quite complex task is probably very futile.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Windows Desktop Sharing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968809.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Win VNC [http://dotnetvnc.sourceforge.net/](http://www.realvnc.com/) download and use their API.

Comment: thanks, this is a somewhat relevant to my question. I guess up front I don't have any way to determine if what .net VNC does is the same as what TeamViewer and Citrix do, but at least this is clearly step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is not a direct answer to my question, but nevertheless an interesting discussion of the issue [How is TeamViewer so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498877/how-is-teamviewer-so-fast) . The OP is asking a question similar to mine and provides his empirical analysis of the competing systems. He says that Windows Remote Desktop is significantly faster than VNC, presumably because it transmits Windows drawing commands rather than bitmap diff, and he also says that TeamViewer is surprisingly faster than even that, for reasons he wants to understand.